# Как добавить цвет заливки по SVG из url(".svg") в CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

Пытался вставить цвет. А по результату не изменилось

```
.icon {
  fill: red;
  background: url("https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/57a245dbf22749a73c2095bc/57ade47d1fd32dc352ace5b5_5774494a52b43cbe655759a1_home.svg");
}
```